# openfire automatic subscription accept

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I' ve installed subscription plugin for openfire and I've made the settings to accept all local subscription request.
However when I try to add a user to my roster it's subscription type still seems 'none' but what I wanted here is as soon as I add a user to my roster it's subscription type should be either 'from' or 'both'.  I Think subscription plugin is responsible for that but I dont think its working or I'm missing something
Does anyone know anything about it?

I've also checked the system logs and see the below error:

> 2012.02.17 16:13:48 org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginServlet - org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.SubscriptionPlugin cannot be cast to org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.SubscriptionPlugin
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.SubscriptionPlugin cannot be cast to org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.SubscriptionPlugin
>
> at org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.subscription.subscription_002dplugin_002dproperties_jsp._jspService(subscription_002dplugin_002dproperties_jsp.java:58)

Comment: According to logs, it seems that you have some problems with classloaders - the container where JSP is takes classes from some different location than expected.

Comment: can you suggest me a solution about that?

Comment: please provide more details about application server and environment.

Comment: application server is openfire 3.7.1  and its running on windows xp machine and beside subscription plugin only userservice plugin is installed do you need aditional informatioon?

Comment: well, not sure. I see that the problem is related to classloaders, however nothing specific comes to my mind. Just check you don't have duplicate JAR files or artifacts with different versions (if you are using maven) at the same time. Hope this helps/

Comment: I seem to have the same problem. But it loads both subscribers as if the subscription has been accepted on both sides. Would love to know if you ever solved this?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. In my specific case, the domain that subscription plugin was allowing requests to and from (a domain assigned by EC2), was not what I was using to connect to the server (which was the IP address of the server). When I changed the domain of the server from the EC2 domain to the IP address, the plugin responded as expected.

This might be because the subscription request comes in with the IP address as the domain, whereas the plugin is looking for requests that come from a different domain. This is my understanding, I could be wrong.

I saw this issue only when I was setting the acceptance criteria to 'Accept from the same domain only'. And all this is with respect to the Subscription plugin by Ryan.